# how to fill bezier curve gdi c

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+, bezier

I need to fill the closed besier curve with colour...can anybody help me to improve this code because it doesn't work:

```
    COLORREF collor = RGB(100,50,150);
    CPen g(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 50, collor);
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(90, 100, 128));
    pDC->SelectObject(&g);
    CPoint Pt[10]=
{ 

    CPoint(400, 260),
    CPoint(480, 260),
    CPoint(500, 260),
    CPoint(470, 290),
    CPoint(450, 350),
    CPoint(470, 370),
    CPoint(430, 370),
    CPoint(420, 391),
    CPoint(405, 410),
    CPoint(400, 260),
};
    pDC->PolyBezier(Pt, 10);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select a brush which has been created as a solid color with the color you want to fill with.

```
CBrush brush;
brush.CreateSolidBrush(collor);
CBrush * pOldBrush = (CBrush *) pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
...
pDC->SelectObject(pOldBrush);
```